# Initializing NSS using Certificate DB

Tags: firefox, certificate, browser-plugin, nss

I am writing a NPAPI plugin, from which i need to access firefox certificate store.
I have included the Gecko SDK and i want to initialize NSS with the default certificate DB.
I am unable to find on how to obtain the certificate DB path programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer. It can be done only using xpcom library. But alternatively, the solution which i use currently is, i read the profile.ini from "%APPDATA%/fozilla/firefox". This file contains the profile directory path for all the profiles created. Also the current profile that is active will contain a property "default=1" . In this way the default path for the certificate DB could be obtained